# Save Fragment data when switch to another fragment using Navigation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I just started with my first Android project. My application contains two fragments that are connected with the navigation controller.

As for now, all I have on my first fragment is only two EditText. However, I realize that when I switch to my other fragment and navigate back, the texts entered have been cleared.

So I would like to know what I can do to save the date and restore them when I switch it back

I have already tried saving them in **onSaveInstanceState()** as suggested by the majority of people, however, it is not working. So I did a little test, turns out the **onSaveInstanceState()** is not even being called when I switch the fragment. Instead, **onDestroy()** and **onPause()** are being called, ones where people don't recommend to save my data

I have also tried to use ViewModel to save the data but it seems that the data saved into the ViewModel is also gone when I switch back to the original Fragment.

So I am not sure what to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ViewModel, create your ViewModel by Activity instead of Fragment, inside your Fragment.onViewCreated() method

```
val myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(activity as ViewModelStoreOwner).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: This is what i wrote:    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java);

Comment: @YanZhuang try to change "this" to "activity as ViewModelStoreOwner" as param

Comment: I tried. But turns out, with my BottomNavigationController, when I switch the fragment, it is actually completely destroyed (onDestroy() being called). So I don't know how to save the state if everything is being destroyed